# Add icon to status bar - Qt

Tags: c++, qt, icons

I have an icon that is saved in a format:

```
//icon.h
extern const unsigned char icon[];

//icon.cpp
const unsigned char icon[]={0x17,0x3f,0x0c,....,0x10,0x06}
```

Now i want to add this icon to the status bar.

How do i do it?

Thank you.

Comment: i added a button to the status bar and did statusBtn->setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap((const char*)icon)));, but it doesn't work

Comment: Use a QLabel, Button involves more work!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First create a widget that loads the icon data, like a QLabel on which you set a [QPixmap](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop). What format is that image in? You will have to load it into your pixmap using one of the constructors, or you could try loading it with [`loadFromData()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#loadFromData).

Then add that widget to the status bar like so:

```
statusBar()->addWidget(yourIconWidget);
```

Have a look at [`statusBar()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#statusBar), [`addWidget()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstatusbar.html#addWidget) and [`addPermanentWidget()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstatusbar.html#addPermanentWidget).

An example of how to create the widget could be:

```
QPixmap *pixmap = new QPixmap;

// Note that here I don't specify the format to make it try to autodetect it, 
// but you can specify this if you want to. 
pixmap->loadFromData(icon, sizeof(icon) / sizeof(unsigned char));

QLabel *iconLbl = new QLabel;
iconLbl->setPixmap(pix);

statusBar()->addWidget(iconLbl);
```

Specifying the format, as I mentioned above, is elaborated upon [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#reading-and-writing-image-files).

Comment: I don't really understand how to create the icon widget. can you please give me and example?